# How to select an element place after an a element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code. Why this isn't working if I would like to select the `<a>` element if clicked?

```js
$('input[name="USR_NewPassword"] span > a').on('click', function(event) {
  alert()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" name="USR_NewPassword" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required>
<span class="input-group-addon">
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
    </span>
```

Comment: Because the `<span>` is not a child of the `<input>` element -> [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Comment: @Andreas, so more this `input[name="USR_NewPassword"] > span > a` ?

Comment: No -> [MDN: CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Ok, sonore something like this: `input[name="USR_NewPassword"] + span > a`. Thanks for your help. It works.

Comment: You can answer your own questions... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `+`:

```js
$('input[name="USR_NewPassword"] + span > a').on('click', function(event) {
  alert();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" name="USR_NewPassword" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required>
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye">icon</i></a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selection is wrong. Use `next` with `find`.

```js
$('input[name="USR_NewPassword"]').next('span').find('a').on('click', function(event) {
  alert();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" name="USR_NewPassword" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required>
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye">icon</i></a>
</span>
```